# BFS bad complexity

Tags: time-complexity, ocaml, breadth-first-search

I am using adjacency lists to represent graph in OCaml. Then I made the following implementation of a BFS in OCaml starting at the node `s`.

```
let bfs graph s=
    let size = Array.length graph in
    let seen = Array.make size false and next = [s] in 
    let rec aux  = function 
    |[] -> ()
    |t::q -> if not seen.(t) then  begin seen.(t) <- true;  aux (q@graph.(t)) end  else aux q 
    in aux next
```

`size` represents the number of nodes of the graph. `seen` is an array where `seen.(t) = true` if we've seen the node `t`, and `next` is a list of the node we need to see.

The thing is that normally the time complexity for BFS is linear (O( V +E)) yet I feel like my implementation doesn't have this complexity. If I am not mistaken the complexity of `q@graph.(t)` is quite big since it's O(| q |). So my complexity is quite bad since at each step I am concatenating two lists and this is heavy in time.

Thus I am wondering how can I adapt this code to make an efficient BFS? The problem (I think) comes from the implementation of a Queue using lists. Does the complexity of the Queue module in OCaml takes O(1) to add an element? In this case how can I use this module to make my bfs work, since I can't do pattern matching with Queue just as easily as list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the complexity of q@graph.(t) is quite big since it's O(| q |). So my complexity is quite bad since at each step I am concatenating two lists and this is heavy in time.

You are absolutely right – this is the bottleneck of your BFS. You should be happily able to use the `Queue` module, because according to https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/comparison_of_standard_containers.html operation of insertion and taking elements is O(1).

One of the differences between queues and lists in OCaml is that queues  are mutable structures, so you will need to use non pure functions like `add`, `take` and `top` that respectively insert element in-place, pop element from the front and return first element.

Comment: Thank you ! If I was implementing a DFS instead I guess the complexity of my algorithm would be ok ? Since the only change is that q@graph.(t) is transformed into graph.(t)@q and I get a complexity of O(graph.(t)) so in this is case this is ok.

Comment: Yes, it would be correct because in this `@` you would process each node at most one time

Answer (score -1):

> If I am not mistaken the complexity of q@graph.(t) is quite big since it's O(| q |).

That is indeed the problem. What you should be using is `graph.(t) @ q`. The complexity of that is O(| graph.(t) |).

You might ask: What difference does that make?

The difference is that |q| can be anything from 0 to V * E. graph.(t) on the other hand you can work with. You visit every vertex in the graph at most once so overall the complexity will be

```
  O(\Sum_V |grahp.(v))
```

The sum of all edges of each vertex in the graph. Or in other words: E.

That brings you to the overall complexity of O(V + E).

Comment: In this case it’s a DFS not a BFS

Comment: You have to process the list from the end. That can be achieved by having 2 lists. One you are currently working and one for appending future vertexes. Then every time the current list is empty you reverse the future list and start again.

Comment: This is a traditional immutable queue then. Why didn't you mention this solution in your answer?